# Outliers formula for columns in pandas

Tags: python, pandas, numpy, scipy

I have an example of numerical column in a `df` having 10 other columns (both numerical and categorical):

```
Units
-12
4
4
5
1
5
12
6
34
6
7
12
745
```

I would like to apply the formulas:

```
Low outlier: q1-(1.5*iqr)
High outlier: q3+(1.5*iqr)
```

I know that there is `iqr` in `scipy`: `from scipy.stats import iqr` and using `numpy`  I can calculate `q1` (first quartile) and `q3` (third quartile) as follows:

```
from scipy.stats import iqr
import numpy as np

q1=np.percentile(df.Units, 25)
q3=np.percentile(df.Units, 75)

mask = df['Units'].between(q1, q3, inclusive=True)
iqr = df.loc[mask, 'Units']
```

However there are two missing steps in calculating the formulas above:

- handle `NaN` values: I would prefer to not remove them from my column, but only to exclude them from calculations;
- correctly apply the formulas

Low outlier: q1-(1.5*iqr)

High outlier: q3+(1.5*iqr)

I would say that maybe it could be possible by using `between` or just filtering values lower/higher than values calculated from the formulas above.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Lazy attempt with `df.query`, excludes `NaN`s from calculations and keep them in the final query:

```
from scipy.stats import iqr

df = pd.DataFrame([-12,4,4,5,1,5,12,6,34,6,7,np.nan, 12,745], columns=["Units"])

q1 = np.nanpercentile(df.Units, 25)
q3 = np.nanpercentile(df.Units, 75)
IQR = iqr(df.Units, nan_policy="omit")

df.query("Units.isnull() or ((@q1 - 1.5*@IQR) <= Units <= (@q3 + 1.5*@IQR))")
```

which gives the (hopefully) expected result:

```
    Units
1     4.0
2     4.0
3     5.0
4     1.0
5     5.0
6    12.0
7     6.0
9     6.0
10    7.0
11    NaN
12   12.0
```

Comment: Thank you, Filippo. I am getting this error: TypeError: unhashable type: 'numpy.ndarray' , because of the last line of code (df.query).

Comment: @Val may be something with your Units column, does it work with the dummy data in my example? Does df.Units.isnull() return the same error outside df.query? What's df.Units dtype?

Comment: @Val maybe it's something about the [modified Python syntax](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/version/0.24/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.query.html) used inside df.query. You could try using `|` instead of `or` inside the query expression or add the argument `engine='python'` (I'm just blindly guessing, be aware)

Comment: I think the reason of the error was because of `isnull`. Also, I did not replace `np.percentile` with `np.nanpercentile`. Now it seems working fine. Thank you so much, Filippo